# Save in local storage

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am creating a php+mysql webform. Is there any way for me to save the input local storage and when there is internet then push up to mysql server? because if a user finish filling the form and submit till half way then the previous filled data will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/ this will not only give you that feature but it will make it easy :)

You could use this code to accomplish part of what you are looking for:

```
$('form').sisyphus({
  timeout: 0,
  onSave: function() {
    console.log('Saved!');
  }
});
```

Comment: I have downloaded the sample and i found 3 failures is there anyway i can fix that?
-should save textfield data on key input, if options.timeout is not set

-should save textarea data on key input, if options.timeout is not set

-should fire callback on saving data to Local Storage